# Prove an idempotent invertible 2x2 matrix in general linear group $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ must be the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, systems-of-equations

The general linear group of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{R}$ (all $2 \times 2$ invertible real matrices with matrix multiplication), is a group. In any group $G$, if $a \in G$ is idempotent i.e. $aa=a$, then

$$a=ae=a(aa^{-1})=(aa)a^{-1}=(a)a^{-1}=e$$

In $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, the identity is $e=I_2= \begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 0 &1\\ \end{bmatrix}$. I want to show without using the above result that if $A \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is idempotent, then $A=I_2$.

Suppose $A=AA$, so

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\\ \end{bmatrix}=A=AA= \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a^2+bc & b(a+d)\\ c(a+d) & d^2+bc\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

Thus, $a^2+bc=a,\, d^2+bc=d,\, b(a+d)=b,\, c(a+d)=c$. Using the last two equations, we have $c(a+d-1)=0=b(a+d-1)$. There are three cases: $b=0$, $c=0$, or $a+d=1$.

I used the additional fact that $A$ is invertible and $ad \neq bc$ to show that $A=I_2$ for $b=0$ and $c=0$. Notice that if $\text{tr}A=a+d=1$, then it is impossible to have $A=I_2$, but I have had no success with finding a contradiction. What breaks if $\text{tr}A=1$?

Perhaps we can use that $\text{det}A=ad-bc=1$ for any invertible idempotent matrix (since $(\text{det}A)^2=\det A$)?

Comment: I suggest that you are wanting to work tooooo hard on this. The thing that you say you don't want to use is the way to understand the question. Everything else obscures the reasons and mechanisms...

Comment: Hint: This matrix is invertable, how can you use that to simplify A^2 = A?

Comment: Hint: In a group the only element that satisfies $xx=x$ is $x=e$.

Comment: The fact that an idempotent $a \in G$ must be the identity was proven in the original post. And using invertibility of idempotent $A$ would be the same proof, namely $A=AI=A(AA^{-1})=(AA)A^{-1}=(A)A^{-1}=I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a + d = 1$, we have

$a^2 + bc  = a$

$\iff a(1-d) + bc  = a$

$\iff -ad + bc = 0$

contradicting that det $A \ne 0$

From this we immediately get

$ b = c = 0$

Furthermore

$a, d \ne 0$ since $A$ is invertible and now $a^2 = a$ and $d^2 = d$ gives $a = d = 1$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a linear algebra approach:

Note that $A^{2} = A \implies f(A) = 0$, where $f(x) =x(x-1)$.

This means that the minimal polynomial of $A$, denoted by $m_{A}(x)$, can only have three possibilities for it must be a divisor of $f(x)$ and those three possibilities are:

$m_{A}(x) = x, x-1$, and $f(x)$. If $m_{A}(x) = x$ or $x(x-1)$, then $\lambda = 0$ would be an eigenvalue of $A$ and that would mean $\det A =0$, which is a contradiction since $A \in GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$. Hence, the only possibility is that $m_{A}(x) = x -1$.
We then have by the definition of a minimal polynomial that $0 = m_{A}(A) = A -I \implies A = I$, as it was promised.

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{aligned}
0=A^2-A
&=\pmatrix{a^2+bc-a&b(a+d-1)\\ c(a+d-1)&d^2+bc-d}\\
&=\pmatrix{a^2-(ad-bc)+ad-a&b(a+d-1)\\ c(a+d-1)&d^2-(ad-bc)+ad-d}\\
&=(a+d-1)A-(ad-bc)I\\
&=\left(\operatorname{tr}(A)-1\right)A-\det(A)I.
\end{aligned}
(Basically, we have reproved Cayley-Hamilton theorem for $2\times2$ matrices.) Therefore $\left(\operatorname{tr}(A)-1\right)A=\det(A)I$. Since the RHS is nonzero, $\operatorname{tr}(A)-1 $ must be nonzero too. In turn, $A=kI$ for some $k\ne0$. So, from $A^2=A$, we get $k^2I=kI$. Hence $k=1$ and $A=I$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a+d=1$, then

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & 1-a\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

and $A = A^2$ implies

$$\begin{bmatrix} a^2+bc & b\\ c & 1-a\\ \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & a^2+bc-2a+1\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

and we must have $$a^2-a+bc = 0$$

But this implies $\det A = 0$; which is a contraction, since $A$ is invertible. So $a+d \ne 1$.

Comment: Using $A$ as specified in this answer, we have $A^2= \begin{bmatrix} a^2+bc & b \\ c& bc+a^2-2a+1 \end{bmatrix}$. I think the answer will be clearer if the bottom right terms of the two matrices are swapped after writing "and $A^2=A$ implies..." so that the left hand side is $A^2$ and right hand side is $A$.